# regexp special character

Tags: regex, sed, grep

How to do in grep or sed for regexp with special characters?

I want to search a pattern "This is a (test)" from a text file which the file contains the following lines:

This is a test
This is a (test)!
This is a (test)

Only line 3 is the result I want to return, is it possible?

Comment: What's the difference between line 2 and 3?

Comment: There's typo, Amended

Comment: `grep '^This is a \(test\)$' file`

Comment: Thanks Avinash, how about if "This is a (test)" is a substring and located in the middle of the line?

Comment: @KennethLui, if it's _located in middle of the line_ why the second line should not match?

Answer (score 0):

grep option -F treats all characters literally:

```
grep -F 'This is a (test)'
```

from `grep --help`

> -F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated strings

however

```
grep -F 'This is a (test)' <<END
This is a test
This is a (test)!
This is a (test)
END
```

`This is a (test)!` matches also if pattern ends with word boundaries `-w` can help

```
grep -Fw 1 <<END
12
1
END
```

otherwise special characters must be escaped

```
grep '^This is \(a test\)$'
```

or perl extension `\Q..\E` can be used to escape special characters between `\Q` and `\E`

```
grep -P '^\QThis is a (test)\E$'
```